# Tree traversal using std::for_each

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am fairly new to using `algorithm` and `functional` in C++. I need to do tree traversal and perform a function for each element. See the code below.

This works but a I have few things I don't like and perhaps can do better. Note that I am limited to a fairly old version of g++ (4.4.7) and cannot use lambda functions.

1. I use a wrapper function `do_walk` and `std::bind` to call the member function `walk` on each element. Is there a way to avoid the wrapper function and directly call the member function?
2. I use a typedef for the callback function `UnaryFunction`. I would prefer to use a templated version of `walk`. However, when I change the code to use a template I get the following compilation error: `error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::_Placeholder<1>&, void (*&)(const Elem&))'`. Is it possible to use templates in this context?
3. Perhaps there is an alternative to `std::for_each` that is better suited for this kind of tree traversal?

My code so far:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Elem;
typedef void (*UnaryFunction)(const Elem&); // (2)

struct Elem
{
    std::list<Elem> children; // Some container, std::list for now.

    //template< class UnaryFunction > // (2)
    void walk(UnaryFunction f) const
    {
        // Walk all children.
        std::for_each(
            children.begin(),
            children.end(),
            std::bind(do_walk, std::placeholders::_1, f)); // (1)

        // Walk this object.
        f(*this);
    }

    //template< class UnaryFunction > // (2)
    static void do_walk(const Elem& elem, UnaryFunction f) // (1)
    {
        elem.walk(f);
    }
};

void pretty_print(const Elem& elem)
{
    // Pretty print element.
}

int main()
{
    Elem root;
    // Create tree somehow.
    root.walk(pretty_print);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think usually questions seeking feedback on working code should be posted on Code Review, not SO.

Comment: @underscore_d I can imagine this one being in scope for both, as it is asking a specific question about a language feature which doesn't work as expected (even if a workaround is present in the question).

Comment: you can use `std::bind(&Elem::walk, std::placeholders::_1, f));` so you don't need `do_walk`

Comment: @appleapple - not noticed; thanks.

Comment: for range (C++11) is a good alternative to `for_each` -> `for (auto& elem : children) { elem.walk(f); }`. It should be enabled in gcc 4.4.7

Comment: @Jarod42 nope, I tested this and gcc 4.4.7 does not support range-based for loops. Introduced in 4.6 according to [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).

Comment: :/, so `for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it) {it->walk(f);}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `std::bind` is capable of invoking member functions (passing the first argument to the implicit `this` parameter), so you can replace `do_walk` with this:

   ```
   std::bind(&Elem::walk, std::placeholders::_1, f)
   ```
2. The problem with making `walk` a template is that at the time of `bind`ing, it's not clear which instantiation should be used. You can disambiguate that by explicitly specifying the template argument:

   ```
   std::bind(&Elem::walk<UnaryFunction>, std::placeholders::_1, f)
   ```
3. I believe `std::for_each` is fine.

[[Live example]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rpaX86RoVqSTNqtG) using gcc 4.4.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::function instead to solve problem with template walk.
Let's sumarryze:

> I use a wrapper function do_walk and std::bind to call the member
>   function walk on each element. Is there a way to avoid the wrapper
>   function and directly call the member function?

Yes. Use std::function

> I use a typedef for the callback function UnaryFunction. I would
>   prefer to use a templated version of walk. However, when I change the
>   code to use a template I get the following compilation error: error:
>   no matching function for call to 'bind(, std::_Placeholder<1>&, void (*&)(const Elem&))'. Is it possible
>   to use templates in this context?

Yes. Use std::function + variadic templates

> Perhaps there is an alternative to std::for_each that is better suited
>   for this kind of tree traversal?

I think std::for_each is OK for this purpose

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


struct Elem
{
   std::list<Elem> children; // Some container, std::list for now.

                          //template< class UnaryFunction > // (2)
   template<typename ...TArgs>
   void walk( std::function<TArgs...> f ) const
   {
       // Walk all children.
       std::for_each(
           children.begin(),
           children.end(),
           f ); // (1) NO WRAPPER
   }
};

void pretty_print( const Elem& elem )
{
    // Pretty print element.
}

int main()
{
   Elem root;
   Elem root1;
   root.children.push_back( root1 );

   // Create tree somehow.
   root.walk<void( const Elem& )>( pretty_print );
   // or root.walk<decltype( pretty_print )>( pretty_print ); if you do not 
   // want to clarify type
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::function` is not free, it has a runtime overhead on each call (because the call has to be `virtual`) and doesn't play too nicely with inlining. `std::function` is useful when you need to *store* an arbitrary callable, but shouldn't be necessary when you just need to *call* one.

Comment: @Angew: Nit… it doesn't have to be virtual, but it will almost certainly be indirect (in C++ terms either a virtual call or a call through a function pointer). libstdc++'s `std::function` is implemented in terms of two function pointers (an "invoker" that implements `operator()`, and a "manager" that is responsible for copying, destruction etc.), and an `_Any_data` that basically contains the functor's data, if small enough and nothrow-movable, or a heap pointer to it.

Comment: Correction: It doesn't check for nothrow-movable, because `std::function` is not nothrow-movable. I consider this a standards defect. It's also inconsistent with `std::any`.